# Azure Application Insights not showing exceptions in Blazor server application

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, blazor-server-side

I've been using Application Insights for a few years on various ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core projects, and usually it is a breeze to set up and get exceptions to show up in the portal.  For my Blazor Server applications, errors don't bubble up to the AI portal.  Is there an additional set of packages required or setting that needs to change specifically for Blazor Server?

ASP.NET Core 6.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all type of log information for your blazor app in application insights you have to add the  **"DetailedErrors": true** in your appsettings.json file.

```json
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
    }
  }
}
```

There are two ways (**Error Boundaries** & **Global Exception Handling**)to Add Error logs to application insights [Blazor Server unhandled exceptions in application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-server-unhandled-exceptions)

> Note: Native Application Insights support for Blazor WebAssembly apps, as well as native Blazor framework support for Google Analytics, may be available in future releases of these technologies. Refer [MSDOC's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#log-errors-with-a-persistent-provider) for more information

Blazor programs use the **Console Logging Provider** by default to log to console output. Consider logging to a server address (or a **backend web API for Blazor WebAssembly programmes**) with a log size and rotation provider. Alternatively, an **Application Performance Management (APM)** service, such as **Azure Application Insights**, can be used by the app (Azure Monitor).

To aid in debugging, a **Blazor Server app typically sends the complete details of errors to the browser's console during development**. **Detailed errors aren't given to clients in production**, but the complete details of an exception **are logged on the server**.